# Add2LinkedList -- gives SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python

Need debugging help. Gives following error while printing the result. I tried the suggestion provided by intelligent IDE suggestions and putting result variable in function braces(result.val, end=" ") but its not printing the expected output: "7 0 8"

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.

class ListNode(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.val = x
    self.next = None


class Solution:    
  def addTwoNumbers(self, l1, l2, c = 0):    
    # Fill this in.
    l1 = ListNode(2)
    l1.next = ListNode(4)
    l1.next.next = ListNode(3)
    l2 = ListNode(5)
    l2.next = ListNode(6)
    l2.next.next = ListNode(4)
    result = Solution().addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)

while result:
    print result.val,
    result = result.next

# 7 0 8
```

> File "C:/Nityam/PythonProjects/DailyProblems/Add2LinkedList.py", line 21
>      print result.val,
>            ^
>   SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean >print(result.val, end=" ")?
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is caused by running Python 3 but using Python 2 syntax `print thing`, which should be `print(thing)`. The error message tells you what to write instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message states, try replacing this:

```py
print result.val
```

With this:

```py
print(result.val)
```

The first is Python 2 syntax, while you seem to be running your code in Python 3. Just add in the parentheses when calling `print` and the problem should be solved.